# Line not visible on holidays in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to draw a line based on time(say, start datetime to end datetime). Need a way to find if there is trading holiday or not based on datetime. Since the lines are not visible if the end datetime is a holiday.

Check this code below:

```
    var dev_start_time = 0
    dev_start_time := time_close(resolution)
    var dev_end_time = 0
    if resolution == "D"
        dev_end_time := time_close(resolution) + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
    else if resolution == "W"
        dev_end_time := time_close(resolution) + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
    else if resolution == "M"
        dev_end_time := time_close(resolution) + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
    else
        dev_end_time := time_close(resolution) + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12)

    while dayofweek(dev_end_time) == dayofweek.saturday or dayofweek(dev_end_time) == dayofweek.sunday
        dev_end_time := dev_end_time + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)

    // Need to check for holidays here

    _aLine = line.new(x1=dev_start_time, y1=_price, x2=dev_end_time, y2=_price, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=_line_color, width=line_width)
    line.delete(_aLine[1])
```

Comment: If you want to do that then you need to create the dates manually. because there is no `syminfo.*` command which tells you the holidays of countries nor exchanges.